# Docker containers visible in Portainer but not in Docker CLI

Tags: docker, portainer

I'm trying to access my docker containers through the CLI, usually I manage them through Portainer, they all show up there, no problem :

[image: Portainer containers]

But when I do `docker container ls` , I get nothing .

---

My Portainer local env is set to :  **/var/run/docker.sock**
and I believe my docker context is the same :

`docker context ls`

`default *   Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

I there something else I should do to see the same containers in the CLI as in Portainer ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, I had two parallel installs of Docker one from apt one from snap, removed the snap one